# Reload a webview after turning on internet

Tags: android, webview, reload

I am trying to load a url into a webview. If there is internet connection, it should load it to the webview. Otherwise, a try again screen should be shown. In the try again screen, i have a try again button. If we click on it, the url should be loaded again. But with the code i've done, the app keeps crashing when i try to reload the url by clicking on try again button(even after i turn on net or if its still off). This is my code

```
    tryAgainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tryAgainLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            open(browser);
        }
    });



private void open(View view){
    browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    browser.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient());
    mContext=this.getApplicationContext();
    browser.loadUrl(target_url);
    MainActivity.this.progressBar.setProgress(0);
    browser.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

How can i reload the page on clicking on the try again button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of assumption here as there is no logcat:

1. App crashes because you try to get the browser view by searching for it in the wrong layout/view.
2. If you just want to reload, it would be better to just do a **browser.reload()** int he click listener

**EDIT** Simple solution: create a listener class and pass the webView as a parameter to constructor so it knows what to reload.

```
class WebViewReloader implements View.OnClickListener{
    private WebView browser = null;

    public WebViewReloader(WebView target){
        browser = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        tryAgainLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        browser.reload();
    }
}
```

and then

```
tryAgainButton.setOnClickListener(new WebViewReloader(browser));
```

Other solutions: use a static reference to the WebView, or retrieve WebView by searching in its parent layout.

Comment: i tried doing that too. But still it crashes. In the logcat i get a nullpointer exception for the browser(Webview object)

Comment: You must be sure to search the web view (call to findViewById) using the corect layout/view. You call findViewById on the Button view and that will always return null. I will edit my answer with a proposal.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. But still the app crashes. I guess i have made some mistake somewhere. This seems like the answer.

Comment: I dont know wether its the proper way or not. But i did this and it worked now                               tryAgainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tryAgainLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });